# Remove spaces in SHA256 output

Tags: ios, encryption, sha256

Can anyone solve my problem related to SHA256 in iOS?

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

NSData *dataIn = [@"XXXXX" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_SHA256(dataIn.bytes, dataIn.length,  macOut.mutableBytes);

NSLog(@"dataIn: %@", dataIn);
NSLog(@"macOut: %@", macOut);
```

I getting output like this :

```
2014-10-14 10:46:43.602 sha256[480:70b] dataIn: <416e616e 64>
2014-10-14 10:46:43.604 sha256[480:70b] macOut: <e9fb6a39 4db5ffd6 dba9b31a c7d9a90d 56f90767 afaf1e14 d6dcaa37 db180932>
```

what i actually need is i need to remove space in macOut. i.e  like this

Comment: ya i gothrouged but i need clear steps to remove space from output log ?

Comment: Why do you need to?  The space is just there for readability.  It's not actually part of the data...

Comment: ya i understood but my team expecting to remove space from it, actually this data should b validate in web service thats y they asking to find solution to remove space

Comment: i want my output like this : <e9fb6a394db5ffd6dba9b31ac7d9a90d56f90767afaf1e14d6dcaa37db180932>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this below your code:

```
NSString *macOutString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", macOut];
NSString *encryptedString = [macOutString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"macOut: %@", encryptedString);
```

You can also verify the encryption with - http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator

Comment: @user3744674 Please mark the answer correct to close this question.

Comment: can u help me for another doubt in SHA 512 the same step i implemented for SHA 512 also  NSMutableData *macOut = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH]; my output is: <dcc9733144e1990fe109304394ed58f8b2624ef5ee40fd45d557fd5716bc2d9c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000> iam getting more zero's i think its wrong can u help me in coding

Comment: @AnandFresher Answer is the same. Try to understand the logic instead of asking every question. You need to convert NSData to NSString in order to remove spaces. I am sure a Google search would help that. Good luck - SHA512 - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2GmKmSjC

Comment: once again Thanks @raurora its worked, i didnt handle SHA 512 and ShA 256 that y iam keep on asking the steps anyways once again thank you bro :) god bless

Answer (score 0):

Create NSData, NSString category use this code at https://github.com/mdznr/iOS-Passcode/blob/master/Passcode/NSString%2Bsha256.m

Comment: This is a link only answer, always describe at least what the code in the link does and (if unclear) how it helps to solve this question.